# Django Tutorail - Part 3 - Cannot Access Model Values

Tags: django

I did the entire django site tutorial and I am now trying to redo it without consulting the tutorial, to see which parts I remembered and which I did not.

I can successfully load a template when I go to the correct url.

**post_list.html**

```
 <h1>The Blogs Index Page</h1>
 <h2> Posts </h2>

{% for post in latest_post_list %}
<p> {{ post.title }}<p>
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   body = models.TextField()
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

**Relevant views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import Post

def index(request):
   latest_post_list = Post.objects.order_by('pub_date')
   context = {'latest_post_list': latest_post_list}
   return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context)
```

The page only displays the H1 and H2 tag information, everything else is just blank. I have a suspicion that `latest_post_list` does not exist.

When using the shell, I am able to...

```
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> Post.objects.all()
[<Post: First Post>, <Post: Second Post>, <Post: Third Post>]
```

So the titles exist. I am at a loss to why I can not access my `post.titles` from the Template.

Comment: You are calling `blog/index.html` as the template in your view, but the template where you have the logic is `post_list.html`?

Comment: You are completely right. I was using the wrong template, that and my URL system is a little messed up.